# GET API request not working 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, axios

Anyone familiar with the OpenWeather API and having any issues with it since lately?
I am following along with Stephen Grider's React and Redux course where I have to get an API connection with them, this went okay until today, now I am getting a 404 error? Anyone familiar with this?

This is my code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const API_KEY = "3ce22afbb4c9b6c452574b28666ed63d";
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = "FETCH_WEATHER";

export function fetchWeather(city) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return {
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

I have edited out the first 3 and last 3 characters.

Comment: Observe the console of your browser (Network tab), and see if the request URL and other fields are set properly.

Comment: what is the city you have given? If the city is invalid you will get 404 back